# Preventing multiple spurious calls to backend in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a service class in Flutter that fetches objects from the server using Rest API calls. It caches those objects and returns cached objects if the UI tries to fetch the same object again. Like this:

```
Future<User?> getUser(int userid) async{
   User? u = _userCache.get(userid);
  if(u == null) {
    ApiResponse<User> ar = await _restapi.getUser(userid);
    if (ar.successful && ar.data != null) {
      u = ar.data!;
      _userCache.add(userid,u);
    }
  }
  return u;
}
```

Now, the problem that I am having is as follows: The UI requires the same User object  multiple times while building a screen and so, it invokes getUser(id) multiple times. Ideally, it should return the cached User for the second and subsequent requests but the first request to the server hasn't completed yet and the cache does not have the User object (even though it will have the object a few seconds later). This causes the app to invoke the Rest API calls multiple times.

I want to basically have just one active/pending call to the RestAPI. Something like this:

```
Future<User?> getUser(int userid) async{
 >>>> CHECK whether a call to backend is pending. If so, then wait here.<<<<
  User? u = _userCache.get(userid); <--This call should now succeed
  ...same as before
}
```

Is this how it should be done? What is the right way to achieve this?

====== UPDATE =================

Based on @dangngocduc suggestion my getUser method now looks like this:

```
Future<User?> getUser(int userid) async{
  User? u = _userCache.get(userid);
  if(u == null) {
    await userLock.synchronized( () async {
      u = _userCache.get(userid);
      if(u == null) {
        ApiResponse<User> ar = await _uome.getUser(userid);
        if (ar.successful && ar.data != null) {
          u = ar.data!;
          _userCache.add(userid, u!);
        }
      }});
  }
  return u;
}
```

Comment: Cache your `User` object in SharedPreference as json string.

Comment: *"Is this how it should be done? What is the right way to achieve this?"* - use [MapCache](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.cache/MapCache-class.html)

Comment: I am sorry but I checked out MapCache but didn't understand how that solves my problem.

Comment: `getUser(int userid) { return mapCache.get(userid, ifAbsent: (uid) => _restapi.getUser(uid).data); }` - thats all, it either returns existing future or calls real api if it is called the first time for given uid

Comment: @pskink This doesn't work for me for the following reasons:
1. I use cache_it package for caching because it has ttl feature. MapCache that you are referring to doesn't seem to have it. If it has, then its documentation is awful.

2. It doesn't tell what happens when you try to retrieve a key multiple times in quick succession. The first miss will cause the backend call but what happens to the subsequent calls while the first call to the backend is still pending? Again, poor documentation.

Comment: MapCache does avoid multiple requests when first one is still pending. It would be absolutely useless without it. Comment excerpt from map_cache.dart:  Map of outstanding ifAbsent calls used to prevent concurrent loads of the same key.

Comment: @lev5, Your comment is as information deficient as the documentation. What do you mean by "avoids multiple requests"? Does it return null? Does it await? does it do double checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is on first time, when we don't have cache and have multiple request for a user.

I think you can try with this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/synchronized

Let add your logic on synchronized.

Comment: Your suggestion was very helpful. Thank you!